# Can I decorate class to skip if error is found during deserialization in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, attributes, json.net, deserialization

I have an api that returns json. I am using JSON.NET to deserialize into objects.

```
public sealed class ConfigurationCount
{
    [JsonProperty("count")]
    public int Count { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("game")]
    public MyEnums.Game Game { get; set; }
}
```

Essentiall using:

```
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ConfigurationCount>>(json);
```

To return a list of ConfigurationCount.

However, sometimes, the json property "game" cannot be converted to a MyEnums.Game. In this instance, I just want to skip deserialising this object into the list.

Is there any way I can decorate the ConfigurationCount class with something that might just skip on error? e.g.

```
[JsonObject(OnError = Skip)]
public sealed class ConfigurationCount { ... }
```

I'd prefer not to write a custom JsonConverter, as I'm not not sure how I'd even do that on a per object basis.

Kind regards

Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do something like this:

```
public sealed class ConfigurationCount
{
    [JsonProperty("count")]
    public int Count { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsValid => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnums.Game), game);

    [JsonProperty("game")]
    private int game { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public MyEnums.Game Game
    {
        get
        {
            if (!IsValid) throw new InvalidOperationException("Object is invalid");
            return (MyEnums.Game) game;
        }
        set { game = (int) value; } 
    }
}
```

Then you just deserialize everything, and remove the ones where IsValid is false.

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm. This'll cover me whilst I argue with the backend guys to fix their data ;)